# Setting and getting data value from service in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So this is my service that I use to fetch user details.

```
angular.module('app')
.factory('userDetailService', function($http) {
    var userData = {};

    function getUserDetails(userId) {
        if (userId) {
            return $http.get("/users/" + userId).success(function(data) {
                angular.copy(data[0], userData);
            });
        }
    }
    return {
        userData: userData,
        getUserDetails: getUserDetails
    }
})
```

Now in `Controller 1` that uses this service, I have this bit of code which works fine as I get the relevant data.

```
$scope.getUserId = function(userId) {
        if (userId) {
            $scope.userData = userDetailService.userData;
            userDetailService.getUserDetails(userId).success(function() {
                console.log($scope.userData); //Prints valid user data
            });
        }
 };
```

After this function executes in `Controller 1`, I try to do the following in `Controller 2`:

```
$scope.userData = userDetailService.userData;
console.log($scope.userData); //Prints null
```

But `$scope.userData` is null. Isn't the whole purpose of using a service to share data between controllers? Since I have already set the value of `userData` in `Controller 1`, shouldn't I be able to access it in `Controller 2`?

Weirdly enough, the modal dialog which is the template for `Controller 2` is able to access data in the form of `{{userData.first_name}}` or `{{userData.last_name}}`. If this works, why is `$scope.userData` null? What am I missing?

Edit:

Template 1:

```
<div id="myModal" ng-controller="Controller 1">
<modal-configure-user></modal-configure-user>
    <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#configureUserModal" href="#" ng-click="getUserId(user.id)" data-id="user.id">{{user.first_name + ' ' +user.last_name}}</a>
</div>
```

Template 2:

```
<div ng-controller="Controller 2"  id="configureUserModal">
</div>
```

Both are modal dialog windows.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about the connection between sctrl1 and 2? inheritance? diffrent views? diffrent routes? when does 1 executed and when is 2?

Comment: @BenDiamant I've put that in as well.

Comment: Please try console.log(userDetailService.userData) in both controller. service instance will be unique everytime you accessed from any controller. also ensure that service has loadded data before it logs it.

Comment: @JenishRabadiya `console.log(userDetailService.userData)` didn't work as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach is not very reliable, since you can't be 100% sure that data has already loaded when you try to access it in the second controller. Instead of assigning user data to variable always invoke `getUserDetails` method, which returns a promise. Then you just need to cache loaded data to avoid duplicated requests.

```
angular.module('app')
.factory('userDetailService', function($q, $http) {

    var userData;

    function getUserDetails(userId) {
        if (userId) {
            return userData ? $q.when(userData) : $http.get("/users/" + userId).success(function(data) {
                userData = data;
                return userData;
            });
        }
    }

    return {
        getUserDetails: getUserDetails
    }
});
```

Wrapping `userData` into [`$q.when`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#when) creates a promise object, which resolves immediately. This is what you need, because service API is now consistent - you always deal with promises.

The usage in both controller then would be:

```
userDetailService.getUserDetails(userId).then(function(data) {
    $scope.userData = data;
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this! So let's say I do `$scope.userData = userDetailService.getUserDetails(userId);` in `Controller 1`. Now how would I access this userData in `Controller 2` without passing in the ID and making a request again?

Comment: More specifically, how do I "cache loaded data to avoid duplicated requests" as you said?

Comment: See the answer, I added example.

Comment: If I do this once in Controller 1, then won't it make another request when I call it in Controller 2? What if I only want to pass the `userId` in Controller 1 and I just want to fetch the `userData` for that `userId` in Controller 2?

Comment: If data has loaded once in some of your controllers, then it will be cached and `userDetailService.getUserDetails(userId)` will resolve immediately.

Comment: Thank you. Your answer works but I need to figure out a way to do this without having access to the `userId` in the second controller!

Comment: Use something like this in the second controller: http://plnkr.co/edit/FjlJqSWmvHAf7HoTmEwr?p=catalogue Save promise in variable and in the second controller get this promise and use it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67113/discussion-between-geekchic-and-dfsq).